# How to replace words in similar links in BeautifulSoup4?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am new to web-scraping and Beautifulsoup4 and I want to replace the number "375" with number "700" . I have no clue that how can I do that  ,Here's the link

https://www.wallpaperup.com/uploads/wallpapers/2017/04/22/1086857/48df69b50d7601215c6509cb7bd6ab69-**375**.jpg

I want this link to be like this

https://www.wallpaperup.com/uploads/wallpapers/2017/04/22/1086857/48df69b50d7601215c6509cb7bd6ab69-**700**.jpg

I am using python 3.6 and urllib3.

Comment: add your sample code please and the link is showing 404

Comment: @Tasnuva you haven't read my question perfectly I have written that I am new to it and I don't know how to do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope I understood you right, but simple `str.replace()` will do:

```
original_link = 'https://www.wallpaperup.com/uploads/wallpapers/2017/04/22/1086857/48df69b50d7601215c6509cb7bd6ab69-375.jpg'

new_link = original_link.replace('-375.jpg', '-700.jpg')

print(new_link)
```

Prints:

```
https://www.wallpaperup.com/uploads/wallpapers/2017/04/22/1086857/48df69b50d7601215c6509cb7bd6ab69-700.jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

URL's are just strings. You can manipulate them as strings however you like

```py
mynumber = 700
url = f'https://somesite/{mynumber}'
result = requests.get(url)
```